# Jersey client testing

Tags: java, rest, testing, jersey

I have a Jersey client which performs post request to some black box service.
Also I have POJO mapping feature enabled.
I have integration tests already, they are calling real black box service.
Now I need to test my application without calling real black box service.
**My question is**: how can I test this Jersey client? I mean: how can I test Jersey client without calling real black box service?
Maybe there is some possibility to mock JSON response in tests?

Environment: jersey-client and jersey-json versions - 1.19.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have performed an investigation concerning my question. Mentioned investigation resulted in such facts:

1. I haven't found features/mechanisms/etc. to test Jersey client without real calls to the server (in my case - black box service).
2. Jersey test framework provides features for testing **Jersey server**, but there are no features for testing **Jersey client**
3. The only one solution for testing client without server is to refactor my code in following way: split logic into two phazes. First phaze: get JSON response using Jersey. Second phaze: get JSON response (which we get in first phaze) and transform it into desired object. In general you'll have next code as a result: 
    
   `Class< String > jsonResposeClass = String.class;
   String jsonResponse = post( yourRequest, jsonResposeClass );
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   YourResponseBean bean = mapper.readValue( jsonResponse  , responseClass );`

    
   The solution above will give you a possibility to use mocking libraries like Mockito and mock method which performs post request.

    
   If you have found any other solution/feature/special mechanism/etc which can also help in such kind of situation - please share :)

Answer (score 0):

You can log the request using LoggingFilter to make sure your requests are according to your estimate. For running your test, you can use http://mockable.io/.

P.S. Do not forget to replace the Webtarget URL with MockableIO's URL.

Comment: Hmm...
There is a bit misunderstanding due to mistake in my question.
Now I have corrected the mistake in my post and now it's okay.
The question is: how to test my Jersey client without calling real black box service?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) which has recently introduced a way to create simple mocks for JSON responses. Here is an example:

https://gist.github.com/ptrthomas/35ef9d40623cbeade7388b2cbb29a3b1

While the above example is a "smart" mock, it is very easy to create hard-coded mocks, here is an example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-netty/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/mock/_mock.feature

You can easily read files from JSON by using the `read` keyword.